# Do we have $ U \bigoplus W$ under these circumstances?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

let $V$ be a finite dimensional inner product space with subspaces $W$ and $U$ such that $W \cap U = \{ 0\}$

suppose $W$ and $U^{\perp}$ are isomorphic, is it true that $  V = U \bigoplus W$ ?

I know for one that if $  V = U \bigoplus W$ then necessarily $W=U^{\perp}$

I'm positive it is not true, but I'm struggling to construct a practical counter example, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. Consider the case that $V=\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the usual inner
product. Let $e_{1}=(1,0)$ and $e_{2}=(0,1)$. Let $U=\mbox{span}(e_{1})$
and $W=\mbox{span}(e_{1}+e_{2})$, then $U^{\perp}=\mbox{span}(e_{2})$.
Clearly $U\cap W=\{0\}$ and $W$ and $U^{\perp}$ are isomorphic
(because both are one dimensional). However we do not have $V=U\oplus W$.

Although it is true that for each $x\in V$, there exist uniquely
$u\in U$ and $w\in W$ such that $x=u+w$. However, the condition
$\langle u,w\rangle=0$ is NOT fulfilled. For example, take $x=2e_{1}+e_{2}$,
then we have decompostion $x=u+w$, where $u=e_{1}$ and $w=e_{1}+e_{2}$.
However $\langle u,w\rangle=1$.

---

Remark: If the symbol $V=U\oplus W$ just means: For any $v\in V$,
there exist uniquely $u\in U$ and $w\in W$ such that $v=u+w$, then
the answer is Yes.

Reason: Let $n=\mbox{dim}(V)$, $k=\mbox{dim}(U)$, then $\mbox{dim}(W)=\mbox{dim}(U^{\perp})=n-k$.
Since $U\cap W=\{0\}$, it is not difficult to see that $\mbox{dim}(U\oplus W)=k+(n-k)=n$,
from which we conclude that $U\oplus W=V$.

I work out the details in below: Let $e_{1},e_{2},\ldots,e_{k}\in U$
be linearly independent. Let $f_{1},f_{2},\ldots,f_{n-k}\in W$ be
linearly independent. We asssert that $e_{1},\ldots,e_{k},f_{1},f_{2},\ldots,f_{n-k}$
are linearly independent. Let $\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{k},\beta_{1},\ldots,\beta_{n-k}\in\mathbb{R}$
be such that $\alpha_{1}e_{1}+\ldots+\alpha_{k}e_{k}+\beta_{1}f_{1}+\ldots+\beta_{n-k}f_{n-k}=0$,
then $\alpha_{1}e_{1}+\ldots\alpha_{k}e_{k}=-(\beta_{1}f_{1}+\ldots+\beta_{n-k}f_{n-k})$.
It follows that $\alpha_{1}e_{1}+\ldots\alpha_{k}e_{k}\in U\cap W\Rightarrow\alpha_{1}e_{1}+\ldots\alpha_{k}e_{k}=0$.
Since $e_{1},\ldots,e_{k}$ are linearly independent, we further have
$\alpha_{1}=\ldots=\alpha_{k}=0$. Now, $\alpha_{1}e_{1}+\ldots+\alpha_{k}e_{k}+\beta_{1}f_{1}+\ldots+\beta_{n-k}f_{n-k}=0$
reduces to $\beta_{1}f_{1}+\ldots+\beta_{n-k}f_{n-k}=0$, from which
we conclude that $\beta_{1}=\ldots\beta_{n-k}=0$ because $f_{1},\ldots,f_{n-k}$
are linearly independent.

Since $U+W=\mbox{span}(e_{1},\ldots,e_{k},f_{1},\ldots,f_{n-k})$,
we have $\mbox{dim}(U+W)=n$. On the other hand, $U+W$ is a vector
subspace $V$. Recall that the only vector subspace of $V$ that has
dimension $n$ is $V$ itself. Therefore $V=U+W$. Lastly, we show
that the decomposition $v=u+w$ is unique. For, suppose that $v=u_{1}+w_{1}=u_{2}+w_{2}$
for some $u_{1},u_{2}\in U$ and $w_{1},w_{2}\in W$, then $u_{1}-u_{2}=w_{2}-w_{1}\in W\Rightarrow u_{1}-u_{2}\in U\cap W\Rightarrow u_{1}-u_{2}=0$.
It follows that $u_{1}=u_{2}$, then $w_{1}=w_{2}$.